# How to enable Arabic language in my app?

Tags: android

I tried this code which converts text to speech, but I want the speech to be in Arabic language if the text is written in Arabic.
I looked at other qustions related to this topic, but nothing works with me

The layout has Edit text , button, and TextView.

```js
   


public class AndroidTextToSpeechActivity extends Activity implements
TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
  private int result=0;
  private TextToSpeech tts;
  private Button btnSpeak;
  private EditText txtText;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    btnSpeak = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
    txtText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtText);
    //button on click event
    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
          speakOut();
        }
    });
  }
  //shutdown tts when activity destroy
  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
  // Don't forget to shutdown!
  if (tts != null) {
    tts.stop();
    tts.shutdown();
   }
   super.onDestroy();
  }
  //It will called before TTS started
  @Override
  public void onInit(int status) {
 
  /
  if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
 
  result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);



 if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Missing data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  
   btnSpeak.setEnabled(false);
  } else {
   
   btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
   }
  } else {
      Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
     }
  }
  //call this method to speak text
  private void speakOut() {
  String text = txtText.getText().toString();
  if(result!=tts.setLanguage(Locale.US))
  {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter right Words...... ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }else
   {
    //speak given text
    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you do set the tts language to Locale.US, so that's why it speaks English. Provided your tts engine has Arabic voice data you could set the locale to "ar" instead using the setLanguage method you already use.

It's not clear however if you also need to automatically determine which language the text is written in, that's a whole different story.

Comment: Well, so you have an Arabic voice installed? Perhaps it's also bound to a country code such as ar-EG?